# Why does Win32_PingStatus returns unavailable server but pinging manually works

Tags: excel, server, wmi, ping, vba

I have a excel workbook with a list of hostnames. I am currently using the code below to get the IP of each host name and change the cell color to red and green depending on the status of the server. This code works 99% of the time but on several occasions a server will show as unavailable. But when I manually use ping in cmd, it shows that the server is up. Pinging it manually also show that the round trip isn't taking particularly long so I don't think timeout is the culprit.

Does anybody have any ideas why this is occurring?

```
Private Sub GetServerInfo_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = Worksheets("Inventory_Repository").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 3 To rowCount
        Cells(i, 10).Value = sPing(Cells(i, 4).Value)
        If InStr(Cells(i, 10), "Unavailable") > 0 Then
            Cells(i, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            Cells(i, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("IP has been updated")
End Sub

Function sPing(sHost) As String

    Dim oPing As Object, oRetStatus As Object

    Set oPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
      ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & sHost & "'")

    For Each oRetStatus In oPing
        If IsNull(oRetStatus.StatusCode) Or oRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
            sPing = "Unavailable"
        Else
            sPing = oRetStatus.ProtocolAddress
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues that was preventing me from pinging some of the servers.

The first minor issue was that one of the hostnames had an additional space after it. This will prevent Win32_PingStatus from pinging the correct server. Make sure to strip all the spaces before and after the hostnames.

The second error was the timeout time. By default the timeout is 1000ms. However for busier servers, it can sometimes take a little longer. I added this to my code to extend the timeout to 4000ms which resolved all the servers that periodically failed the ping.

```
Set oPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
      ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & sHost & "' and timeout = 4000")
```